# Lock free consumer producer using memory barrier

Tags: c++, c++11, multithreading, lock-free, producer-consumer

I am looking for "complete" producer-consumer sample using C++11 memory barrier.

(I have derived following example from [Jeff's article](http://preshing.com/20130922/acquire-and-release-fences/) and added a line to make it complete.)

```
void SendTestMessage(void* param)
{
    // Copy to shared memory using non-atomic stores.
    g_payload.tick  = clock();
    g_payload.str   = "TestMessage";
    g_payload.param = param;

    // Release fence.
    std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_release);

    // Perform an atomic write to indicate that the message is ready.
    g_guard.store(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
}

bool TryReceiveMessage(Message& result)
{
    // Perform an atomic read to check whether the message is ready.
    int ready = g_guard.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);

    if (ready != 0)
    {   
        g_guard.store(0, std::memory_order_relaxed);

        // Acquire fence.
        std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);

        // Yes. Copy from shared memory using non-atomic loads.
        result.tick  = g_payload.tick;
        result.str   = g_payload.str;
        result.param = g_payload.param;

        return true;
    }

    // No.
    return false;
}
```

if you notice, i have added `g_guard.store(0, std::memory_order_relaxed);` just before acquire.

This will help following ways

1. It would avoid `TryReciveMessage` to cosnume same message if called multiple times before new message is written
2. It would not add explicit memory fence and hence won't affect performance
3. since `std::memory_order_relaxed` guarantees the ordering, it would get overwritten by `SendTestMessage` value if new load added after the `std::memory_order_acquire` is called. So, we will not miss any load.

Please provide your comments and/or suggestions.

Comment: Can you provide some more context? Especially in multithreaded code it is very important for us to see how functions are expected to be called. Also, we have no idea what the types in `g_payload` actually are,

Answer (score 1):

It's always difficult, and sometimes impossible, to review a snippet of code without knowing how it is intended to be used. In this case, I can say confidently that this code will do the job. Whether that happens to be the job *you* want it to do is another thing entirely.

As long as you understand the limitations of the pattern you're using (and assuming `g_guard` is initialized to `0` properly before either of the functions are called), this will "work".

The limitations are:

- `SendTestMessage()` can only be called ***once***. Not once-per-thread; once for the entire program.
- `TryReceiveMessage()` can be called repeatedly... but ***only non-concurrently in a single thread***.

You didn't say how you intend to use this code, but from your questions, I can deduce that this won't work for you.

1. **It would avoid `TryReciveMessage` to cosnume same message if called multiple times before new message is written**

   With this code, it is safe to call `SendTestMessage()` *EXACTLY ONCE*, concurrently with `TryReceiveMessage()` any number of times *IN A SINGLE THREAD*. So `TryReceiveMessage()` will not consume the same message more than once... but it can also not consume more than one message in total. There can be no "new message".

   Safely synchronizing the guard does *not* safely synchronize the payload. This code "works" only because the payload is written *ONCE*, and then read, with the guard making sure the read is absolutely ordered after the write. If you want to write a *second* time (for a new message): you can't. You'd need a second guard to prevent the second write until after the read is finished. That would turn `SendTestMessage()` into a blocking call... and then you might as well just use regular synchronization techniques.
2. **It would not add explicit memory fence and hence won't affect performance**

   "Performance" is always a vague term. There are many different ways for code to be performant.

   If your goals are:

   1. You want to minimize inter-thread synchronization costs.
   2. You don't care how long you have to wait to receive the message.

   Then this code is about as performant as it can be.

   Note that "performance" in this case doesn't mean "fast". After you call `SendTestMessage()`, you could end up waiting a *looong* time before `TryReceiveMessage()` realizes that there's a message ready. If you have other things to do in the receive thread, that's fine I guess. But if all you're doing is a busy-wait spin... this is *not* the best design for this.
3. **since `std::memory_order_relaxed` guarantees the ordering, it would get overwritten by `SendTestMessage` value if new load added after the `std::memory_order_acquire` is called. So, we will not miss any load.**

   I assume there's a typo here, and you mean to say: "since `std::memory_order_` ***release*** guarantees the ordering...." Because `std::memory_order_relaxed` does literally the opposite of guaranteeing ordering.

   But that's just a guess, because I can't make any sense of what you said. I can't even figure out what "it" is that you're concerned about being overwritten: Do you mean `g_guard` or `g_payload`? Are you asking about if you try to call `SendTestMessage()` twice? I can't figure out what you're asking.

Is this the best way to do this? That depends on what "this" is; you didn't say. It's a passable demonstration on how to use thread fences... but it doesn't look like anything that would be useful in a real-world program generally. This setup works for sending *exactly one* message in the entire lifetime of the program, and receiving it exactly once in a single thread. That's not very useful, generally.

If what you want is a way to set up a producer-consumer operation between threads of any kind - multi-consumer, multi-producer, whatever - there are *much* better ways to do it, generally.

Relaxed memory ordering is one of the deepest and darkest corners of C++, and you really shouldn't be screwing around with it unless you're an expert. Unless and until you've done *everything else possible* to speed up your code in a bottleneck, and have confirmed that it is inter-thread synchronization holding you up, you shouldn't even *consider* touching relaxed memory ordering. And even then, you shouldn't.

I'd say the bottom line of this review is: **whatever you're planning to do with this code... don't**.